# Why are Reviewer stats shown only for the suggested edits queue?

Tags: support, review, review-stats

What is it about the suggested edits queue that users may see (by clicking Reviewer stats) the number of reviews a reviewer has made? Alternatively, what is it about the other review queues that users may not see the stats?

To clarify, when I look at a suggested edit review I get something like the image below which includes the Reviewer stats link (highlighted) which is not present when I look at reviews from other queues.

[image: review queue]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is actually a good question :) Part of the answer will be about privacy, I think. Voting is anonymous, so is close voting. Maybe the Suggested Edits queue doesn't have a close vote possibility, and is therefore the only one that allows for transparency.

Comment: I don't remember when the stats link was added... the entire review queue system was revamped a few years back but it might have already been there...? But I'm not sure there's any provable answer to this question either way. @Joachim close reviews are not actually private - you can view a user's review history from their profile... and see who reviewed/voted to close in the post history. The main difference is that it is thought it is specific to the post and not an aggregate number as it is in that review field. 

Comment: @Catija I suggest that the button dates from back before the review system existed, when the suggested edit system was an entirely separate system.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I've removed my close vote.